# In QGIS, a joined layer is not automatically set to edit mode, when edit mode of parent layer is switched on

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I joined some fields of a different layer in QGIS (version 3.34.5) via layer properties, set them to editable and added them to the attribute form of the parent layer.

[image]

However, when I use the form and switch on edit mode on the parent layer, the fields from the joined layer stay greyed out until I manually switch on edit mode for the joined layer.

Am I missing something or is this the way it should work? How can I automatically activate edit mode for the joined layer, when edit mode of the parent layer is activated (same for deactivation of edit mode)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is by design, as discussed here:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/36934#issuecomment-640681128

There is even a tooltip to that effect ("This option enables editing of the joined layer, **if it is itself editable**") on the "editable layer" checkbox:
[image]

Still, this makes editing awkward; it should be possible to toggle edit mode of the joined layer directly from the form; and not having to toggle edit mode of the joined layer in the layer tree...

Also, the icons described in the [manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/joins_relations.html#joining-features-between-two-layers) don't show up neither on the layer form, nor on the attribute table (QGIS version 3.34.5):
[image]

[image]